# Restreaming flv stream - how to do it correctly?

Tags: flash, streaming, flv

After two days of hard working, reading specs, analyzing hex dump of flv's I feel frustrated. I'm trying to restream flv streming.
I slightly modified my old code of shoutcast restreamer but no success. I can't figure where is the problem, probably flv-streming can`t be just cutted in random position and send to other user with header aadded.
Flv header which I extracted from many dumped flv's: 46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 01 64 00 1E FF E1 00 1E 67 64 00 1E AC 24 A4 02 20 49 BF F0 01 80 01 11 00 00 03 00 01 00 00 03 00 32 8F 16 2D 92 01 00 05 68 EE B2 C8 B0 3E 00 00 00 08 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AF 00 11 90 0F 00 00 00 09 00 40 25 3B E8 19 48 00 00 00 17 01 00 00 A0 00 00 40 1C 09 10 00 00 00 01 67 64 00 1E AC 24 A4 02 20 49 BF F0 01 80 01 11 00 00 03 00 01 00 00 03 00 32 8F 16 2D 92 00 00 00 01 68 EE B2 C8 B0 00 00 00 01 65 88 80 00 01
VLC detects codesc and two streams (video+audio) but fails to play actual content (black stop-frame).
If it can help I can provide samples dumped from original stream server (which I trying to re-stream) and samples produced by my restreming server.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest headache is capturing the stream and encoding it correctly. Do try a different [stream recorder](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/record-rtmp-flash-video-flv-stream-embedded-t2324.html) software and check if your source isn't a RTMPE (encrypted) stream. As VLC is the defacto player, if VLC can't play it, chances are the file is corrupted or encrypted.

Next is to determine if the captured video is supported by ShoutCast (eg: [NSV format](http://www.scvi.net/))?. Some video format cannot be streamed, if this is the case you will have to [reencode](http://www.scvi.net/software.htm) the flv file.

Hope this info helps.